# How to model state that can have either of 2 fields in React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an item of state that can either have it's own value, or reference another item via an id.

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  value: { valueLiteral: number } | { id: string };
}
const item1: Item = {
  name: "foo1",
  value: {
    valueLiteral: 1
  }
};
const item2: Item = {
  name: "foo2",
  value: {
    id: "some-id"
  }
};
```

I need to have an array of these items and pass them to a React component, and have the component render differently depending on whether `value` has a `valueLiteral` or `id` property.

This code works but gets a TypeScript error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wilbur-i4bvjm?file=/src/App.tsx

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  value: { valueLiteral: number } | { id: string };
}
const item1: Item = {
  name: "foo1",
  value: {
    valueLiteral: 1
  }
};
const item2: Item = {
  name: "foo2",
  value: {
    id: "some-id"
  }
};
interface State {
  items: Item[];
}
const state: State = {
  items: [item1, item2]
};
function Item({ item }: { item: Item }) {
  if (item.value.id) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - ID = {item.value.id}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {item.name} - VALUE = {item.value.valueLiteral}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.items.map((item) => {
        return <Item key={item.name} item={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ valueLiteral: number; } | { id: string; }'.
> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ valueLiteral: number; }'.ts(2339)

How can I fix this error given my data modelling requirements?

I could have separate ID and value fields and make them both optional. This avoids the TypeScript errors but is less type safe as TypeScript doesn't prevent `Item` from having both or neither `value` and `id`, but this is not valid for my data modelling.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-euler-h65899?file=/src/App.tsx

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  value?: number;
  id?: string;
}
const item1: Item = {
  name: "foo1",
  value: 1
};
const item2: Item = {
  name: "foo2",
  id: "some-id"
};
// item3 is invalid
const item3: Item = {
  name: "foo3",
};
// item4 is invalid
const item4: Item = {
  name: "foo3",
  id: 'some-other-id',
  value: 2
};
interface State {
  items: Item[];
}
const state: State = {
  items: [item1, item2]
};
function Item({ item }: { item: Item }) {
  if (item.id) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - ID = {item.id}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {item.name} - VALUE = {item.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.items.map((item) => {
        return <Item key={item.name} item={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can get this to work if you say `value: { id?: undefined; valueLiteral: number } | { id: string; valueLiteral?: undefined }` or if you use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions).

Comment: will `any` with a `?` work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (item.value.id) {...}` means if `item.value.id` is truthy, but `{ valueLiteral: number }` has no `id` so how can I check that? That's what TS complains about.

TS doesn't get what you're implying with that check.

But you can use the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for that.

`if ("id" in item.value) {...}` means if `item.value` is an object that has an `id` property. Here TS can understand that you're differentiating between an object with and one without an `id` property.

```
function Item({ item }: { item: Item }) {
  if ("id" in item.value) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - ID = {item.value.id}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {item.name} - VALUE = {item.value.valueLiteral}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a type or interface for the `value`:

```
interface ValueLiteral {
  valueLiteral: number;
}

interface ValueId {
  id: string;
}

interface Item {
  name: string;
  value: ValueLiteral | ValueId;
}
```

And then check the type:

```
function isValueLiteral(value: ValueLiteral | ValueId): value is ValueLiteral {
  return "valueLiteral" in value;
}

function Item({ item }: { item: Item }) {
  if (isValueLiteral(item.value)) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - VALUE = {item.value.valueLiteral}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - ID = {item.value.id}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error while still maintaining the type safety, you can use **type guards**. I believe this would fix your problem:

```
function isValueWithId(value: any): value is { id: string } {
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && 'id' in value;
}
...
...

  if (isValueWithId(item.value)) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {item.name} - ID = {item.value.id}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
else{
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {item.name} - VALUE = {item.value.valueLiteral}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}}
```